# Is it possible to filter out files from the file dialog in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

My specific use case is with an Android project, but this isn't Android specific. I have an IntelliJ-IDEA project with several Android modules which have been localized. If I want to open the file `strings.xml`, I will pretty much always want the non-localized one (in `res/values` rather than `res/values-fr` or whatever). But when I hit `<ctrl><shift><n>` and type `strings.xml`, it shows all the 30-zillion localized files and in fact shows them before the non-localized one. I would like to figure out a way to give IntelliJ a hint as to which one I would want, or a way to filter out files from that dialog. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the checkbox for "Include non-project files" unticked?

Comment: Yes, it is unticked. I suppose I could explicitly exclude all the localized folders from the project.

Comment: looking for this feature too

Answer (score 1):

Seems there is a kind of workaround with directory exclusion

http://devnet.jetbrains.com/thread/283525